# How to vstack multiple astropy tables using a loop

Tags: python, astropy, vstack

I have a list of astropy tables and I want to vstack them all using a loop.

This is what I have:

```
tables = []

for i in range(len(sortedfiles)):
    tables.append(openfits(sortedfiles[i]))
```

which creates a list where each element is an astropy table. I have a total of 144 such tables.

I want to vertically stack them so I have effectively just the one astropy table but I cannot think of the right kind of loop. Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 3):

You are very close!  All that is left is:

```
from astropy.table import vstack
table_stacked = vstack(tables)
```

What you have done to read all the tables up front to a list of `Table` followed by a single `vstack` operation at the end is the right way. Do not use `vstack` within the loop since this will be slower.